# Processing a GPX file with xsl (probably a namespace issue)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This question looks like a duplicate of [XPath query for GPX files with namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364825/xpath-query-for-gpx-files-with-namespaces), but I must be missing something because I can't seem to get a fairly simple style sheet to work. I have this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" creator="Groundspeak Pocket Query" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0 http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/cache.xsd" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0">
  <name>Ottawa Pocket Query</name>
  <wpt lat="45.348517" lon="-75.825933">
    <name>GC3HXAZ</name>
    <desc>Craft maker box by FishDetective, Traditional Cache (2/2.5)</desc>
    <url>http://www.geocaching.com/seek/cache_details.aspx?guid=e86ce3f5-9e75-48a6-b47e-9415101fc658</url>
    <groundspeak:cache id="2893138" available="True" archived="False" xmlns:groundspeak="http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0">
      <groundspeak:name>Craft maker box</groundspeak:name>
      <groundspeak:difficulty>2</groundspeak:difficulty>
      <groundspeak:terrain>2.5</groundspeak:terrain>
    </groundspeak:cache>
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

And a stylesheet that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--  -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:groundspeak="http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0"
        >

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    Cache names:
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//wpt">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wpt">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="groundspeak:cache/groundspeak:name"/></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And what I would *expect* is a list with one element on it, "Craft Maker Box", but what I get is an empty list.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default namespace is `http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0`. You should add that and use a prefix to match `wpt`.

Something like this: (untested)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:groundspeak="http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0"
        xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
        >

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    Cache names:
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//gpx:wpt">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="gpx:wpt">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="groundspeak:cache/groundspeak:name"/></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a namespace issue. You have

```
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
```

in the XML so unprefixed element names are in this namespace. You need to bind the same uri to a prefix in your stylesheet, e.g.

```
xmlns:g="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
```

and then use `g:wpt` in the match and select expressions.